# Google code project resource not found error

Tags: google-app-engine, svn, tortoisesvn, google-code

I am trying to download  the  project source from https://code.google.com/p/sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth/source/checkout  but tortoise SVN tells me file not found. what could be the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Are you using the URL http://sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ to check out from? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: try using the follwing command on console..and update your URL first...svn checkout http://sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Comment: Thanks Robin it is working how to identify this?

Answer (score 0):

The URL `https://code.google.com/p/sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth/source/checkout` points to Google Code's web interface. You can't use this particular URL with Subversion client.

The URL that Subversion client accepts is `http://sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`, so the command you should run is `svn checkout http://sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`. The same as stated on the checkout help page here: https://code.google.com/p/sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth/source/checkout.